# Capistrano/Passenger error @ nginx using nokogiri - incompatible library version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, nokogiri, passenger

I'm lauching my rails app with capistrano but the following error message appears at `nginx.log`

```
[ E 2019-09-13 17:16:40.3640 4469/To age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/deploy/eurotec-crm/current: The application encountered the following error: incompatible library version - /vendor/cache/ruby/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.4/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so (LoadError)
  Error ID: 4276d735
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-sxGWLJ.html

[ E 2019-09-13 17:16:40.3689 4469/Ta age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:276 ]: [Client 2-2] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 4276d735. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
```

So I tried to fix the problem following these links:

- [Error about nokogiri while capistrano deployment on ubuntu server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17213728/error-about-nokogiri-while-capistrano-deployment-on-ubuntu-server)
- [Nokogiri gem install failing in Capistrano deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31222528/nokogiri-gem-install-failing-in-capistrano-deploy/31337549)
- [Incompatible library version: nokogiri.bundle requires version 11.0.0 or later, but libxml2.2.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18818926/incompatible-library-version-nokogiri-bundle-requires-version-11-0-0-or-later)
- [LoadError: incompatible library version - /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@lm5/gems/nokogiri-1.8.2/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50100264/loaderror-incompatible-library-version-home-ubuntu-rvm-gems-ruby-2-3-1lm5?rq=1)
- ["Incompatible library version" on nokogiri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32832899/incompatible-library-version-on-nokogiri)
- [We're sorry, but something went wrong. - with Rails, Apache, Passenger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513450/were-sorry-but-something-went-wrong-with-rails-apache-passenger)
- [LoadError: incompatible library version - nokogiri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45548488/loaderror-incompatible-library-version-nokogiri)

And, finally: [capistrano deploy can't install nokogiri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23041232/capistrano-deploy-cant-install-nokogiri).

I googled a lot, followed all the steps that I could find - including reinstall all gems, reinstall all  system dependencies, restart server infinite times, cry a little...

Can anyone shed some light, please?